# How do I make by "put on hold for being too broad" question less broad?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, close-reasons

This question [How to properly namespace bootstrap 3 to work with other bootstrap 3 instances which are not namespaced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908819/how-to-properly-namespace-bootstrap-3-to-work-with-other-bootstrap-3-instances-w) was closed as too broad. 
I can't think on how to make it less broad as i have one precise problem:  Bootstrap developers choose to use really common class names like `.row` or `.table` and i use bootstrap in a wordpress plugin and i need a simple and reproducible way to namespace classes to `.namespace-row` and `.namespace-table` because otherwise if a them or another plugin style `.row` and `.table`.
I could make it less general by saying "i want to do this after compiling bootstrap with Lessphp" but this wouldn't be true, i just need this to be done at any level, i might do it with a regexp

```
find /path/to/css/directory -type f -name \*.css -exec perl -i -pe 's|([\.#])([a-z][^\s,]+)|$1ai1ec-$2|gi' {} \;
```

but maybe there are better options.
Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

Be more specific about the problem you are having.

In your question, it's clear that you're having a namespacing problem, but not at all clear what the nature of your specific problem is.  Also, we don't know what you mean by "efficient."

Showing us some code that illustrates your problem would help.

Comment: Ok i made the question a lot less broad

Answer (score 2):

I see this as being too broad because it is asking for a very broad category of answer, since there are probably multiple ways to do this and a lot could be said about it.  It would seem less broad if you could give a specific situation you're in, and specific code examples that you are looking at.

Having said that I see that this question could easily be seen as "primarily opinion based", since you're just asking for a recommendation on how to proceed.  It would probably be better placed on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), though I would try to tighten the question up to be more focused.